# Why 2.8em is divided by 1.2?

Tags: css, font-size

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to learn the concept of font. I saw this code online,  I understand by default 1em  = 16px but I don't understand why 2.8em is divided by 1.2? What is the reason behind it or is it unnecessary?

```
h1 { font: 700 2.8em/1.2 "Droid Sans", sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the short-hand `font` syntax for defining both `font-size` and `line-height`; specifically a `font-size` of `2.8em` and a `line-height` of `1.2`. You can consult the MDN on [the `font` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) for more details.

Comment: thank you so much! now everything starts to make sense :)